# Different cocoapods for app and Today extension

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-extensions

I am using several pods in my iOS app that make reference to `sharedApplication`, and as such cannot be compiled for a Today extension.

The thing is I really need `AFNetworking`, so I'd like to be able to tell CocoaPods to just include `AFNetworking` when compiling the extension. Is there a way to do this? I've looked through the documentation but it's not clear.

Answer (score 3):

To do this you just need to specify multiple `target` blocks in your `Podfile`. For example:

```
# Normal app pods

target :extension, :exclusive => true do
  link_with 'extension'

  # My extension pods
end
```

Note that 'extension' here corresponds to the name of your extension target in Xcode.